# ADL fails when there are lambda arguments?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup

quite some time ago i noticed that in Visual C++ 10 ADL fails when at least one of the arguments is a lambda.

```
std::vector<float> vec;
for_each(begin(vec), end(vec), [](float) {});
```

The above fails to compile on VC++10 and 11 (beta) (begin and end are found via ADL). When i convert the lambda function into a regular free function things work just as expected.

I've asked on Herb Sutters blog once and also read some posts on msdn connect and the usual answers were: this is a bug, we havent implemented the latest standard of the lambdas yet which - at that time - was quite understandable. Things haven't been in a baked form yet. On MS connect there have also been disturbing comments that this will not be resolved for the next release i.e. vc 11.

My question is, is this code *expected* to work under the C++11 standard? I cant quite figure that out. Do i really have to prefix my for_each and other algorithms with std:: when I'm using lambdas? 
I somehow suspect that this behavior will not change after vc++11 release.

Comment: what free function do you use?

Comment: something as simple as void f(float) {} even works. or declaring the lambda outside of the function call: auto f = [](float) {};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is perfectly valid code. Any bug-free compiler will be able to compile it. But since MSVC has bug and so is unable to search the function through ADL, then maybe you should not rely on ADL and instead qualify it with `std::` helping the compiler to find the function.

Comment: that confirms what i've been thinking. i also do not see why the combination of lambda arguments and non-lambda arguments should disable ADL. not sure if i like the official microsoft response (instantiate the lambda somewhere else or qualify with std::)  ;)

Comment: @Martin: No, `vector<T>::iterator` is allowed to be `T *` (I suspect this is exactly the problem). Although @refp's answer is a bit long and doesn't confirm your suspicion, it's correct. Although, I can't explain why it works with a free function not parameterized over `std` types.

Answer (score 15):

**The standard doesn't guarantee what you'd want it to..**

With the below in mind we can easily realize that there is nothing guaranteeing that [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) would work in cases similar to the example provided in your post.

---

- `std::begin (c)`/`std::end (c)`

  The  functions are described in the standard as the below quotation:

  ```
  template <class C> auto begin(C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
  template <class C> auto end(C& c) -> decltype(c.end());
  ```

  Though the `Container< ... >::iterator` (which is the return-type of `c.begin ()`) is an *implementation-defined* type.

  <sub>More about the matter can be read upon at **24.5.6 Range Access**, and **23.3.6.1/2  class template vector** (or any other template STL container).</sub>
- `[](){}` - **Lambda Expressions**

  A lambda is an *implementation-defined* type, there is nothing in the standard stating that the resulting object will be of a type which is under *namespace std*.

  It can pretty much exists wherever it wants, as long as it confirms to the other rules set up by the standard.

---

---

**Too Long; Didn't Read**

The types of which `std::begin`/`std::end`/*`a lambda-expression`* yields are not guaranteed to be under *namespace std*, therefore ADL is **not** guaranteed to kick in.

Comment: @David: No, the question is exactly about `for_each`. It even says that `begin` and `end` are found without a problem. I think most people didn't quite read the question correctly. For refp: +1, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Xeo: I thought that ADL was failing to resolve `begin` and `end`. At any rate, taken that there is no guarantee in the standard that the iterators will be in `std`, there is still a bug either in failing to find `for_each` in the case of the lambda (assuming that `std::vector<>::iterator` happens to be defined in `std`) or in ADL finding `for_each` if the lambda is substituted by a function call (if `std::vector<>::iterator` is not defined inside `std`).

Comment: To clarify: begin and end are correctly resolved via ADL in both vc++10 and 11 beta. My question was directed at why ADL for for_each (or any other std algorithm) fails when there is a combination of types that are from namespace std *and* one or more lambdas. I think that vc++ disables ADL when there are lambda arguments. Note that if you pass for_each a lambda that is declared outside the for_each function call ADL does work (which currently is the official work-around from microsoft).

Comment: @refp: thanks for your clarifications! as ive stated above, i'm worried about the combination of lambdas and non-lambda arguments. not qualifying has its drawbacks as you pointed out. for instance begin() and end() in combination with arguments of type std::array<> do not return an iterator defined in namespace std so relying on ADL to find for_each() for instance would definitely fail in this case as expected. My original question was directed at another problem, though.

Comment: @MartinWirth The philosophy of most of us writing [tag:c++] is to never write code that isn't backed up by the Standard, if it's not in the Standard - it's not C++ (that's why my answer is written the way it is). Also your question clearly says: "*My question is, is this code expected to work under the C++11 standard?*", so I fail to see what you are referring to with "*My original question was directed at another problem*".

Comment: @refp: that wasn't criticism on my part :) i just was more thinking about the problems of combining lambda and non-lambda function arguments - which apparently stops ADL from working in vc++. i do agree with all your points regarding the use of qualification and your point that begin and end do not need to have to return anything within std::. i probably should not have mentioned begin and end in my example. i just used these because for_each and begin and end are often used together. i should have come up with another example that does not use standard algorithms at all.

Comment: @refp: Do you realize OP said when he passes a functor instead of lambda, ADL is triggered and `for_each` is found. What does it mean? How come ADL is triggered in that case? Surely, it implies `std::begin()` returns iterator which is defined in `std::` which is why ADL is triggered. So, whether Standard gaurantee ADL or not, the compiler **has** bug, as it doesn't trigger ADL only in case of lambda.

Comment: @Nawaz "*My question is, is this code expected to work under the C++11 standard?*", my post answers this exact question, as well as: "*Do i really have to prefix my for_each and other algorithms with std:: when I'm using lambdas?*".